# Mod_rewrite in apache not working with "hidden" /index.php (but working with index.php)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I wrote the following mod_rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !index\.php$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !redirect\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L,R]
```

Which works great except you actually have to go to `/index.php`

What I mean is that if you go to `example.com/index.php` it works fine but not in `example.com` (which actually is index.php - you just don't see it).

Of course it doesn't work for `example.com/` either.

Could anyone help me how to establish this exception.

Thanks in advance, please ask anything that is no clear enough!

EDIT:

I'll try to put it simpler:

The code as it is redirects ALL URLs to http://google.com

except index.php and redirect.php

So when the URL is `example.com/index.php` it doesn't redirect (which is fine)

Wut when the URL is `example.com` is DOES redirect and I don't want it to.

Clearer?

Comment: Just to double-check, you do have DirectoryIndex set to index.php, yes?

Comment: @Andrew Yes. (if by that you mean that example.com is actually example.com/index.php). Then yes.

Comment: @Andrew WOW just it case, this might be relevant, I'm doing this locally on MAMP,

Comment: Have removed the C tag as doesn't relate to C.

Comment: I've edited my question, hope it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve but to answer your question directly, add another condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
```

Comment: That is not working, what I'm trying to do is to avoid redirection whenever somebody inputs the url `example.com/` the code as it is only **doesn't** redirect when you enter directly to /index.php is that clearer?

Comment: Yes, and that's what I attempted to answer. Note that I used REQUEST_URI and not SCRIPT_FILENAME.

Comment: @noodl Thank you! yes I copied and pasted.

Comment: @noodl don't know if it matters but my url (because of MAMP) looks like this http://localhost:8888/muycorto.com/

Comment: Yes!!!! it worked!! (I would hug you right about now) ;) don't really understand why though, but the important part is that it works like a charm!!

Comment: hehe. Well, I'm glad whatever you're trying to do is working even though I still don't know what that is :-)

Comment: haha, whenever **I** understand what I'm trying to do, I'll explain! :) all kidding aside thanks again!